# Abelian vs Holomorphic Differentials vs Quadratic Differentials

Tags: dynamical-systems

In dynamics, they talk about Abelian differentials on surfaces, are they the same as holomorphic differentials?

Quadratic differentials are multiple valued and can change sign as you move around a zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An Abelian differential is just a traditional name for a holomorphic or meromorphic differential on a compact Riemann surface.

A quadratic differential is just an element of $S^2(\Omega^1)$, the symmetric square of the sheaf of differentials. I do not really see what you mean when you say «[they] are multiple valued and can change sign as you move around a zero».

Comment: quadratic differentials are not single-valued unless you move to the double cover.  the branching occurs where the quadratic differential is 0, right?  mainly i wasn't sure what "abelian" differentials were.

Comment: @john, as I said, I do not know what you mean by all that.

Comment: John, could you give a reference?  Like Mariano, I'm confused as to what you mean.  Maybe it's some terminological difference.

Comment: I think that what John means is that if one tries to write a quadratic differential in the form $(df)^2$ for some function $f$, then one may not be able to find such an $f$ globally, but in trying to do so, one constructs a double cover of the Riemann surface, branched at the zeroes of the quadratic differential.